# D3DImage TryLock Fails

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, d3dimage

I'm using D3DImage as part of my WPF user control. Very rarely, when rendering, the D3DImage.TryLock fails.

So far, I haven't been able to find any documentation as to why D3D.TryLock would fail.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the Remarks section. It states:

> Occasionally, the front buffer becomes unavailable. This lack of availability can be caused by screen locking, full-screen exclusive Direct3D applications, user-switching, or other system activities. When this occurs, your WPF application is notified by handling the IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged event.

It says this in relationship to the `Unlock` method, which pushes the backbuffer contents to the frontbuffer. But I imagine that if you acquire a lock and call `Unlock`, at which point it fails because it cannot write to the frontbuffer for whatever reason, the lock may be retained until it is successfully unlocked, at which time a call to `TryLock` would fail. I imagine something like this:

```
image.TryLock
// image gets written to
image.Unlock // fails for one of the listed reasons, lock is retained

// loop

image.TryLock // fails because lock is already acquired
image.Unlock // succeeds because the previously successful lock is still in
             // place and the issue that caused the previous failure of Unlock
             // has since subsided.
```

I have seen this issue occur in some native DirectX development when using `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` improperly, so it could be your solution. That's about all I have. Hope it helps!

As is stated in that block comment, you can check to see if this is the case by adding an event to the `IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged` event. If it is not, you can handle the issue appropriately by not calling the `TryLock`/`Unlock` combo, essentially skipping a render when the front buffer is unavailable. More information on this event handler can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.isfrontbufferavailablechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And the remarks on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.isfrontbufferavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) have further information on how you can better handle when this event is raised. It states:

> The SetBackBuffer method has an overload that takes a parameter that specifies whether WPF falls back to software rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that even when `TryLock` fails, you must call `Unlock`. The MSDN documentation isn't mentioning this explicitly. See the source code  [D3DImage.TryLock](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Interop/D3DImage.cs,5206041f2579c901,references), it calls `LockImpl`, and that method always increments the internal reference count...